# new Action eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I add to my eclipse plugin popup menu, if i want the popup only on files it work, but if i want the popup to the projects in the package explorer it's not working

```
<objectContribution
               id="com.dal.pedal.popupMenu"
               objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">

          <action
                class="com.dal.pedal.popup.actions.upgradeApplet"
                id="com.dal.pedal.upgradeApplet"
                label="UpgradeApplet"
                 menubarPath="com.dal.pedal.setActive">
          </action>
       </objectContribution>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
  <viewerContribution
    id="com.sample"
    targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
    <action
            class="com.dal.pedal.popup.actions.upgradeApplet"
            id="com.dal.pedal.upgradeApplet"
            label="UpgradeApplet"
            menubarPath="com.dal.pedal.setActive">
      </action>
   </viewerContribution>
 ....
```

For more help see [this](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_popupMenus.htm)

Comment: great, now it works. but then when i click on that i'm getting a message  "The chosen operation is not currently available"

Comment: i fixed it, the class did not implement the current intrface

Comment: Nice. Accept the answer if it helped you :-)